# Netbeans Platform / Eclipse RCP alternatives in .NET

Tags: .net, eclipse, spring, netbeans

Are there any free libraries for .NET like Eclipse / Netbeans / Spring RCP for java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What add-in/workbench framework is the best .NET alternative to Eclipse RCP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232345/what-add-in-workbench-framework-is-the-best-net-alternative-to-eclipse-rcp)

Answer (score 1):

The defacto GUI framework for .NET is WPF, and it is included with the Microsoft .NET SDKs. More info:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation

What specific capabilities are you looking for? WPF/.NET represents more functionality than straight Swing or SWT, but the Eclipse/Netbeans/Spring RCP projects provide a much more comprehensive foundation for *complex* and modular GUI applications.

I don't know of any defacto application frameworks for WPF, but perhaps something like this would be of interest:

- http://waf.codeplex.com/

Comment: I know WPF, but i'm searching from something bigger, for developing complex apps. I'm looking for something similar to Netbeans RCP's modularization (separation, plugin-updater api, etc) and advanced gui building features (like it's internal window handling logic)

Comment: I don't know of anything similar to eclipse/netbeans RCP libraries in the WPF/.NET space. I'm not an expert in WPF/.NET, but I believe the answer to your question, is simply, "no".